# Can I save multiple GeoEntry with the same member in Redis or there are alternatives?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

My aim is to create a cache of road speed limits on Redis (taken from OSM) where searching the position with latitude and longitude, returns the speed limit in a certain radius using GEORADIUS.

The problem is that using:

```
GEOADD speed-limits -45.000000 10.000000 "90"
```

if I add a new position with always the limit of 90 the previous one is overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either

(1) use a compound key as the member
so it is `GEOADD speed-limits -45.000000 10.000000 90:timestamp:location`, and the query would be something like `GEORADIUS speed-limits ... WITHCOORD` and then use `.split(":")[0]` to get the speed.

or

(2) store the speed separately

`GEOADD speed-limits -45.000000 10.000000 timestamp:location` and `SET timestamp:location 90` so it would be a two step query too.

Comment: The second suggestion is perfect even if with a small overhead but much more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It would get overwritten because `90` is already assigned a value.

Generally, you need to choose your keys carefully. Instead of simply storing the speed-limit, you can multiple delimiters such as timestamps,random-hashes or even some other useful information (say city) in this case with the limit.

For example, "90" could be transformed to `90#1606757564#abcde#city_name`.

This way, when you query for the radius, you would get the entire key. Use a simple `startsWith()` check to get the original limit.